# No such element in selenium java

Tags: selenium

```
public class listenerdemo {

    @Test 
    public void login() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
        System.out.println(" The Page Title...." + driver.getTitle());
        System.out.println("The Page URL...." + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofMillis(500));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions. visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy (By.xpath("//*[@id='webklipper-publisher-widget-container-notification-close-div']")));
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

[popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCjdm.jpg)

Comment: Finally i got the solution... for the issue...

Comment: driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
        System.out.println(" The Page Title...." + driver.getTitle());
        System.out.println(" The Page URL...." + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));


        driver.switchTo().frame("webklipper-publisher-widget-container-notification-frame");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='close']")).click();

        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.close();

Comment: _"Finally i got the solution"_ You can add an answer to your own question in order to improve readability if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer